# Is it correct to use device tree from CyanogenMod for AOSP building?

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build AOSP Gingerbread for my Samsung Galaxy Y S5360. So I need the device tree for S5230. I have found it [here](https://github.com/vivekkalady/device_samsung_totoro). But it is for Cyagenmod.

Is it correct to use it in pure AOSP?

Comment: Did you have any luck ? Can you post instructions of what you did ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not see any reasons why you cannot do this. If the drivers in device tree are for the same version of Android, I guess you can download them. The only thing is you should be careful with overlay folder. There are some packages and resource values that can override (or add) unnecessary packages that can cause build fault.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot just build the AOSP for your own device. You need to have the correct drivers and kernel for your device.

Better take the Cyanogenmod version, cause this one will be prepared for your device.

Comment: There are correct drivers [here](https://github.com/vivekkalady/vendor_samsung_totoro) in folder _proprietary_ and there is kernel for my device in device tree.